# Flutter IOS Universal Link Opens App, But Does Not Navigate To Correct Page

Tags: swift, flutter, ios-universal-links, flutter-ios, apple-app-site-association

I have set up Universal Links on my flutter project for IOS.

Like the title suggests, my app does open when I click on a link relating to my site but it does not navigate to the correct page. It just opens the app.
I'm not using the [uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) package, rather I used a combination of guides (including official documentation):

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/717/

https://nishbhasin.medium.com/apple-universal-link-setup-in-ios-131a508b45d1

https://www.kodeco.com/6080-universal-links-make-the-connection

I have setup my apple-app-site-association file to look like:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "details": [
            {
                "appIDs": [
                    "XXXXXXX.com.my.appBundle"
                ],
                "componenents": [
                    {
                        "/": "/*"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and I have added this to my info.plist file:

```
<key>FlutterDeepLinkingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

and my AppDelegate.swift file looks like:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, 
    restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    // This will allow us to check if we are coming from a universal link
    // and get the url with its components
    // The activity type (NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb) is used
    // when continuing from a web browsing session to either
    // a web browser or a native app. Only activities of this
    // type can be continued from a web browser to a native app.
    guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
      let url = userActivity.webpageURL,
      let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {
        return false
    }
    // Now that we have the url and its components,
    // we can use this information to present
    // appropriate content in the app
    return true
  }

  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

My Runner-entitlements are also setup correctly like:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
<array>
    <string>applinks:www.example.com</string>
    <string>applinks:*.example.com</string>
</array>
```

The issue is, if I click a hyperlink for [www.example.com/mypath](http://www.example.com/mypath) , it does not got to the page/route handled by /mypath, but instead just opens the app.

My routing is done using [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router): ^5.2.4

Please does anyone know why this is happening? I'm blocked by this. I have seen similar questions, but none with answers that have worked for me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting the components included in the links?

Comment: @MayankVerma not really sure what you mean, but I also tried adding a component that hardcoded a path in my app, still got same results. Basically "/": "/feed" as a component but when i clicked www.example/feed, same result...it just opened the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so figured it out. The official apple documentation requests the addition of a variation of this function in the AppDelegate.swift file:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, 
    restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    // This will allow us to check if we are coming from a universal link
    // and get the url with its components
    // The activity type (NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb) is used
    // when continuing from a web browsing session to either
    // a web browser or a native app. Only activities of this
    // type can be continued from a web browser to a native app.
    guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
      let url = userActivity.webpageURL,
      let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {
        return false
    }
    // Now that we have the url and its components,
    // we can use this information to present
    // appropriate content in the app
    return true
  }
```

Seems that it conflicts with the flutter framework for handling universal links. Taking that function out and just having this in my info.plist worked (everything else stayed the same):

```
<key>FlutterDeepLinkingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

Flutter documentation is not out for this (as at the time of posting this answer) so if people are interested, I could do a small article on the necessary steps.

Answer (score 0):

When you handle the dynamic link you get the universal link and other data in the userActivity parameter of the following function.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL {
        debugPrint("incoming url is", incomingURL)
        let link = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().shouldHandleDynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: incomingURL)
        print(link)
        let linkHandle = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingURL) { link, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("Error found.")
                return
            }
            if let dynamicLink = link {
                self.handleDynamicLinks(dynamicLink)
            }
        }
        if linkHandle {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Parse the data from another function or you can parse in above code also. In my case I parsed the code in below function.

```
func handleDynamicLinks(_ dynamicLink: DynamicLink) {
    guard let link = dynamicLink.url else {
        return
    }
    
    if let landingVC = self.window?.rootViewController as? LandingViewController {
       // Do you your handling here with any controller you want to send or anything.
    }
          // example you are getting ID, you can parse it here

    if let idString = link.valueOf("id"), let id = Int.init(idString) {
        print(id)
    }
}
```

When you get the details from the link you can simply fetch the navigation controller or the VisibleController, and then can push to the desired flow.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. Problem is that I'm using a 3rd party routing library with flutter and the handledynamiclinks() function would cause conflicts. My question is extremely flutter specific. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: No issues. Best of luck @KosyOnyenso